# Find if there are any capital letters in Google Docs with Regex

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to make sure that there are no capital letters in a document before I process it. I want to use REGEX to test that, but it seems to be failing.

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let text = body.editAsText();
  Logger.log(text.findText("[A-Z\s]+").getElement().asText().getText());  
}
```

The log here is returning the text even when the entire section is lowercase. I don't know if my regex is wrong, my function is wrong, or what. I normally work in Google Sheets, so I'm not used to the Docs GAS functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is used to indicate a set of characters. Any character between those brackets will be captured. For example, `[A-Z\s]+` will match any uppercase letter and space character in your string. Your regex returns lowercase because your section might have a space between words.

To fix it, just remove the `\s` in your regex.

From: `[A-Z\s]+`

To: `[A-Z]+`

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let text = body.editAsText();
  Logger.log(text.findText("[A-Z]+")); 
}
```

**Example:**

Test string 1:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Test string 2:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Since I have spaces in the text I thought I needed the \s. Someday I'll understand regex...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let text = body.editAsText();
  Logger.log(text.findText("[A-Z]")); 
}
```

`[A-Z]` alone is enough to detect an uppercase letter and return the range element.